# com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory - Loading from env variable for Docker

Tags: docker, typesafe-config

I have a Spring Boot based standalone Java application with Akka framework.  This application uses `com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory` for loading config file.

```
ConfigFactory.load();
```

This reads from `application.conf` file.

My `application.conf` will have content like:

```
mongodb-connection {

     username = test
     password = test
 }
```

Now, I am dockerizing this application and would like to pass the password alone as an env variable rather keeping it in the file. But, passing the password through env variable is not working as ConfigFactory reads only from file `application.conf`.

Is there any way to achieve this?